# How to add noise with given autocorrelation to signal in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, noise, autocorrelation, gaussian

My question is a mix of signal processing and Matlab coding.

I have an FIR filter with added noise $w_n$ $$x_n=\sum_{m=0}^{N_h-1}h_mg_{n-m}+w_n.$$

Now the noise $w_n$ has the autocorrelation $$E[w_nw_m]=\sigma^2e^{-|m-n|}.$$

How can I generate this noise in Matlab?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This answer is based on the algorithm from [How to generate exponentially correlated Gaussian random numbers](https://www.cmu.edu/biolphys/deserno/pdf/corr_gaussian_random.pdf).

I will address a slightly more general form of the autocorrelation than is asked for in the question with the requested form being a specific case.

Assume an autocorrelation of the form:
$$R_{xx}(m-n) = E\left[x_nx_m\right] = \sigma^2e^{-|m-n|/\tau}$$
$$R_{xx}(k) = \sigma^2e^{-|k|/\tau}$$
where $k = m-n$.

The specific case requested corresponds to $\tau = 1$.

Let $g_n$ be independent Gaussian distributed with zero mean and unit variance.

Let $\tau>0$ and define the correlation coefficient as:
$$f:=e^{-1/\tau}$$

Define the series $r_n$:
$$r_0=g_0$$
$$r_{n+1}=fr_n+\sqrt{1-f^2}g_{n+1}$$
$$r_n=f^ng_0+\sqrt{1-f^2}\sum_{i=1}^{n} g_if^{n-i}$$

It should be clear that $r_n$ is Gaussian as it is a sum of Gaussians.  The reference proves that this sequence is also zero mean and unit variance (see Theorem 1).

The auto correlation $c(n;m)$ (see Theorem 2) is:
$$c(n;m) \equiv c(n) = f^n = e^{-n/\tau}$$

To generate the sequence requested in the question $x_n$, we need to scale the sequence $r_n$ by $\sigma$ such that the sequence has the proper variance, and set $\tau = 1$ for the proper shape of the autocorrelation function:
$$x_n=\sigma r_n$$

$x_n$ is now Gaussian with zero mean, variance $\sigma^2$, and autocorrelation $R_{xx}(k) = \sigma^2e^{-|k|}$.

```
function [x] = exp_corr(N, tau, sigma)

% [x] = exp_corr(N, tau)
%
% Generates a sequence of Gaussian exponentially corrleated samples
% with the following autocorrelation function
%
% Rxx(k) = sigma^2 * exp(-|k| / tau)
%
% N     - Number of samples to generate
% tau   - Exponent of exponential correlation function
% sigma - Sample standard deviation
%
% Based on:
%   Deserno, Markus. "How to generate exponentially correlated
%   Gaussian random numbers." Department of Chemistry and
%   Biochemistry UCLA, USA (2002).

g = randn(1, N);
r = zeros(1, N);

f = exp(-1 / tau);

r(1) = g(1);

for n = 2:N
  r(n) = f * r(n-1) + sqrt(1 - f^2) * g(n);
end

x = sigma * r;
  
end
```

Comment: Don't know who down votes me or why, but I took a moment to revisit my answer, found a typo and realized I hadn't address the Matlab portion of the question.